# Template node in node-red returns link as encoded HTML entities

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to use a rss parser in node-red and forward the input as a formatted message to slack:

[image: example using reddit news rss feed]

node-red export:

```
[{"id":"f6ecdf35.256ab","type":"template","z":"1573541c.6cc74c","name":"Blog post","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"{{article.author}} has published an article: *{{article.title}}*\n{{article.link}}","output":"str","x":580,"y":640,"wires":[["ffcd3009.7a20c","799b343a.f89a2c"]]},{"id":"4f9293db.e8614c","type":"feedparse","z":"1573541c.6cc74c","name":"reddit news","url":"http://www.reddit.com/r/news/.rss","interval":"60","x":390,"y":640,"wires":[["f6ecdf35.256ab"]]},{"id":"ffcd3009.7a20c","type":"slack","z":"1573541c.6cc74c","name":"","channelURL":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/REMOVED","username":"rss bot","emojiIcon":":robot_face:","channel":"test","x":750,"y":640,"wires":[]},{"id":"799b343a.f89a2c","type":"debug","z":"1573541c.6cc74c","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":750,"y":700,"wires":[]}]
```

The template looks like:

```
{{article.author}} has published an article: *{{article.title}}*
{{article.link}}
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
/u/casac8 has published an article: *Guy who left manure at Treasury Secretary Mnuchin&#39;s house has come forward, cites First Amendment*
https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/7m0ag1/guy_who_left_manure_at_treasury_secretary/
```

but the template returns:

```
&#x2F;u&#x2F;casac8 has published an article: *Guy who left manure at Treasury Secretary Mnuchin&#39;s house has come forward, cites First Amendment*
https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.reddit.com&#x2F;r&#x2F;news&#x2F;comments&#x2F;7m0ag1&#x2F;guy_who_left_manure_at_treasury_secretary&#x2F;
```

### Question

**How can I get the template node to return an unescaped utf8 string?**

### Workaround

My workaround for now is a function node which converts it back:

```
function parseHtmlEntities(str) {
    return str.replace(/&#x([0-9a-f]{1,3});/gi, function(match, numStr) {
        var num = parseInt(numStr, 16);
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    });
}
msg.payload = parseHtmlEntities(msg.payload);
return msg;
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the sidebar help for the template node, to avoid escaping of html entities, you should use triple braces:

```
{{{article.author}}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm so blind!